# Regex expression for patterns that don't begin with numbers python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

i am trying to grasp Regexp using python. I am trying to match patterns wherein the first character of the block of characters cant be a number while the rest can be any number or character or _. The first char can only be _ or characters. e.g

```
7lucky is invalid
_lucky is valid
_7lucky is valid
lucky.john is valid
```

My code:

```
exp=re.compile(r"(\b[_a-z][-a-z0-9.]*\b)")
name="-john"
result= exp.search(name)
```

This accepts `-john` too whereas it should only accept `_` or `a-z` in first place.

Answer (score 2):

This would find nothing for `-john` but find `_john`:

```
import re
exp=re.compile(r"^(\b[_a-z][-a-z0-9.]*\b)")
names=["john","-john","7john","_john"]
for n in names:
    if exp.search(n): 
        print(n)
    else:
        print("not found in :"+n)
```

Output:

```
john
not found in :-john
not found in :7john
_john
```

The difference is I prepended `^` to the pattern, meaning: beginning of line.

---

From the doku: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search

> `re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)`  Scan through string looking for
>   the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a
>   match, and return a corresponding match object. Return None if no
>   position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is
>   different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the
>   string.

`re.search` is not contstrained to find at the begin of a string - use `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)` for an implicit "find at string beginning" search:

```
exp=re.compile(r"(\b[_a-z][-a-z0-9.]*\b)")  # works as well, using match
names=["john","-john","7john","_john"]
for n in names:
    if exp.match(n): 
        print(n)
    else:
        print("not found in :"+n)
```

Comment: It works but if we are finding such patterns in a string where there are no of such patterns it is not working e.g name='-john should not be done _john 7should ". It should return all words except -john and 7should.kindly update

Answer (score 1):

Problem here lies in your boundary: it matches the boundary between `-` and a letter.
You have to rework it another way.

I chose to use a lookbehind to match only when not preceded by a non spacing character, replacing `\b` by `(?<!\S)`:
[`(?<!\S)[_a-z][-a-z0-9.]*`](https://regex101.com/r/Nk2voU/1)

NB: The trailing word boundary is useless, as trying to match `[-a-z0-9.]*` will always stop when no more is met.